# Corona: How to detect the direction of an object with physics

Tags: lua, physics, coronasdk, game-physics

I would like to know how to detect the direction of an object with physics, I mean when is falling down. can it be by a eventListener? any idea how to do it?

I need it for know can I change the spriteSheet.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to detect that? What is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: I have a jet with physics which seems that go from the left to the right, and touching the screen I give it power for go up (it's like the tipical sample) so I want to detect when in the (Y) is increasing and decresing for change the SpriteSheet and simulate that the jet turning. That's what I want to do. you think a good way or there's better ways to do it and how?

Thanks @Mr-D

Comment: any idea how @Mr D              .

Comment: I'm sorry its been ages since I played around with corona so I don't really remember much... I was hopping someone else would answer but from the looks there aren't many corona experts. I'll read some of my old code and some documentation tomorrow and see if I can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the exact angle based on an objects velocity you'd call:

```
 local angle = atan2(xVelocity, yVelocity)
```

This returns the angle in radians, which you can then convert to degrees. This allows for more precise control over the object. Daniel Shiffman wrote a great book involving many aspects of physics simulation over at http://natureofcode.com/book/.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
local xVelocity, yVelocity
local upDown, leftRight         -- upDown = 1 for up, leftRight = 1 for left
....
-- Get speed of physics object here ( Assume normal orientation ---
    xVelocity, yVelocity = physicsObject:getLinearVelocity()
    if xVelocity > 0 then
        print( "Object goes right" )
        leftRight = 0
    end
    if xVelocity < 0 then
        print( "Object goes left" )
        leftRight = 1
    end
    if yVelocity > 0 then
        print( "Object goes down" )
        upDown = 0
    end
    if yVelocity < 0 then
        print( "Object goes up" )
        upDown = 1
    end
-----------------------------------
```